# What's the best place to set up a VPN network in Linux

Tags: server, vpn, openvpn, router

I have a Linux router and an Ubuntu server with both having vpn (openvpn) capabilities. Between the two, which place is the best to set up vpn? I want to set one up tonight, but I still can't decide between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting up a connection in, I would go with the server as the router is a director if traffic. That's it's primary purpose.

If you're setting up a connection out, I would go with the router as that will encrypt all communications coming from said device.